How to use a python virtual environment on QGIS?
I'm currently developing a QGIS plugin and I want to use pydantic in this plugin.
I'm currently using python 3.12 and QGIS 3.36.
It is not recommended to install package in the python system environment according to PEP 704: https://peps.python.org/pep-0704/
I guess the best way to do this is to use a virtual environment but it seems impossible.
Is there any alternatives to do what I need ?

That PEP is withdrawn.  You need plugin users to install dependencies in whatever python environment QGIS uses (QGIS can be installed multiple ways). If QGIS uses system python, dependencies need to be installed so as to be available to system python (i.e user site-packages).

For plugin development purposes, to avoid breaking something in the main QGIS directory I can recommend installing QGIS in a separate folder using OSGeo4W installer.
It's not a virtual environment, but it's probably fine for your purposes.
You may also be interested in Plugin Reloader, which for testing purposes, allows you to quickly move a test version of a plugin from the development folder to the current user's folder without rebooting QGIS.
